# Getting the index of a node in a qgslayertree

Tags: pyqgis

Can I get the `index ([integer])` - not the `ID`- of a child in a `QgsLayerTreeGroup` ?

I'd like to insert a layer using `insertChildNode(int index, QgsLayerTreeNode *node)` in the layer tree. `index` is required for control of the exact position of the inserted layer in the LayerTreeGroup.
The exact position of the inserted layer in the layer-tree depends on other layers. So i can not give a default value as `index`.  I've to calculate this value depending on the `index` of the otherLayer. For this reason I'd like to determine the index-value of the otherLayer. In the API-doc I only read about functions to determine its ID - which seems not to be the same as the `index`.